# Does swapping x1/x2 change the rectangle?

Tags: geometry

I have a small function used to ensure that `x1 <= x2`, and `y1 <= y2`. Here it is, you should be able to see what it does without programming knowledge:

```
if(searchArea.x1 > searchArea.x2){
        int temp = searchArea.x1;
        searchArea.x1 = searchArea.x2;
        searchArea.x2 = temp;
    }
    if(searchArea.y1 > searchArea.y2){
        int temp = searchArea.y1;
        searchArea.y1 = searchArea.y2;
        searchArea.y2 = temp;
    }
```

My question is: will my rectangle always remain the same for all values of x and y > 0 using the above method? I've tried a few small samples, but I don't know if I've tried every case.

Thank you!

Comment: I have no idea what you are asking. What does 'will my rectangle always remain the same' mean?

Comment: Sorry! I mean will my bounds and location of the rectangle remain the same? Like I need the new rectangle to occupy the exact same space as the original.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your rectangle has points $(x_1,y_1)$ and $(x_2,y_2)$, with its sides parallel to the $x$ and $y$ axes. Then its other corners are $(x_1,y_2)$ and $(x_2,y_1)$. Clearly, $(\min(x_1,x_2), \min(y_1,y_2))$ and $(\max(x_1,x_2), \max(y_1,y_2))$ both belong to this set of four corners. Thus the rectangle between them is the same.

Comment: Perfect, I kind of thought that but I wasn't really sure, thank you for the conformation and proof!